# Noise in pulse shaper with wide bandwith (MPPC signal)

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, ground, pulse, routing

I am using an MPPC with voltage amplification with the circuit shown below. The circuit is a pulse shaper to count photons, it counts with 4 amplifying stages (OPA 2846) and a comparator (LT1719) at the end.

The MPPC is powered with +55 V through a coaxial cable and pulse signal is collected by another coaxial cable.

MPPC manufacturer told me that the ideal bandwidth is up to 300 MHz. The problem is that with this configuration I'm having too much gain and a wide bandwidth.

I've made different boards and in all of them I´ve had different issues.

- First I started with 2 different boards both of 2 layer and struggled with the configuration to reduce noise until I have a good signal at the end. For both boards i got two different configurations.
- Then I moved to a 4 layer board (1:-Signal, 2:-Ground, 3:-Power (+5 V,-5 V,3.3 V), 4:-Signal) to reduce noise effect. I copied the configuration used in the 2 layer board but again I got an oscillation near 100 MHz. Finally I removed this oscillation adding a 10 ohm and 100 pF at the output of each op amp to compensate the peak gain, reducing AB.

As you can see I kept the gains of the stages near 10, the resistors seen by the op amp at V+ and V- are of  50 ohms to keep them matched, the 1 kohm resistor seen by the LT1719 comparator are also matched. I keep the traces as small as possible and try to avoid jumping from layer 1 (signal) to layer 4 (also signal).

I want to know if there is a PCB routing recommendation and op amp stages configuration that could improve the SNR and avoid unwanted oscillations.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Would you please share the MPPC datasheet?

Comment: Sure, i´m using the S13360-6075PE wich has the biggest terminal capacitance (1280 pF)   this is the reason because i´m not using the opAmp in transimpedance mode.  https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s13360_series_kapd1052e.pdf

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but there is a high bandwidth pulse shaping MPPC amplifier design on GitHub: https://github.com/OpenSiPM/sipm-bias-control It uses one of the newer MPPCs with lower terminal capacitance but otherwise is pretty close to what you want.

Comment: 1----- Thanks @IgnacioIslas , I work in a similar area as EE/FW/SW, Chromatography. Though I am new to MPPC, [this](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C0604032/papers/0126.PDF) makes sense: Q = C(V −Vbd). When avalanche occurs by photons, Q is discharged. I suspect the "terminal capacitance (1280pF)" represents 'C' there. If that is

Comment: 2----- the case, The voltage on R1 starts with "V-Vd" then decades at R*C rates. I would first try to get right pulse width on input. Once get the pulse (saw-tooth like) in one or two stages at enough amplitude,  the rest could be logic level. I assume you are counting the pulses, not detecting the amplitude. Meantime, in the datasheet, it has inherent Dark Count, which is floor noise, depending on V, since V is over Vbd. Hope my guesses help any.